# How do you render a User control from a ashx or webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, render, ashx, user-controls

Question is it possible to have a .ashx or webservice return a user control rendered? if so how would i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx) from our beloved Scottgu might help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you might be able to do this by calling the [RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607.aspx) method.

Comment: The web-service can in fact send back controls by first converting to string using RenderControl (on serverside) and then, on the client side using {MyDiv = document.getElementById('Div1'); MyDiv.innerHTML = arg;} in the OnComplete method, but I cannot seem to pass on javascript that would execute on the client. Anyone managed to execute javascript using this method?

Answer (score 0):

If your not using MVC, you can get the HTML of a control at bind time by using the RenderControl method.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk91d11a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you can use ASP controls as they need to be inside runaat="server" control. Or at least I still do not have any solution to that problem